# Spin-Orbit perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, hyperfine-structure

I'm trying to use pertubation theory to calculate the energy shift due to spin-orbit interaction between the electron and proton in the hydrogen atom. I'm stuck on how to proceed as this hamiltonian does not commute with L or S, however I have read somewhere that it does commute with $L^2$,$S^2$ and $J$ however I can't seem to prove this. My working is attached and my reasoning would be since the operator is squared, its order doesn't matter hence they cancel however I feel like this is not correct as the square of an operator is just another operator. Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks [image]

Comment: I have realised I didn't include the $1/r^3$ factor, would this make a difference as I still cant seem to calculate it correctly, thanks

Comment: Hint: L and S commute, so you just need to check L^2 and L_j commute as well

Comment: @RyanThorngren Okay thanks and is that from expanding the commutator using the a[b,c]+[a,c]b rule? As I seem to be getting a commutator between S and L^2

Comment: Yes, and by that argument these L^2 type operators quite generally commute with the symmetries they're associated with (since L^2 is the "total" angular momentum, rotations don't change it). They're called Casimir operators. Also, maybe your conventions are different from mine but $S$ and $L$ commute because they act in different indices, it's like a tensor product.

Comment: @RyanThorngren Okay that makes a lot of sense, thank you very much!